# How stop redirect on form submission, but still POST to action URL with Multer?

Tags: html, node.js, express, multer

I'm using Multer to upload images to the server filesystem, and the tutorial I followed suggested to have the form HTML setup as follows:

```
<form action="/upload" id="myForm" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input id="myFile" name="myFile" type="file">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The image file uploads successful, however the user will be redirected to "/upload". From what I researched, Ajax can't handle image uploads and Multer needs the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute anyways.

I had attempted to setup an express route to redirect the user to the previous page, but it seems like express can't get the route since neither of the console.log() are being executed. Here is the code I had for that:

```
 app.get("/upload", function(req, res){
   backURL = req.header('Referer') || '/';
   // need to display "Profile image updated!"
   console.log(backURL);
   console.log("none");
   res.redirect(backURL); 
 })
```

Is there some way to stop the redirect yet still POST to /upload?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I am also using express to post to post the data to /upload:

```
  app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
upload(req, res, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("problem at api-routes line 88")
    res.render('index', {
      msg: err
    });
  } else {
    if(req.file == undefined){
      res.render('index', {
        msg: 'Error: No File Selected!'
      });
    } else {
      db.User.update({
        profileImg: req.file.filename
      },{
        where: {
          id: req.user.id
        }
      }).then(function (dbPost) {
        //res.json(dbPost);
        res.render('index', {
          msg: 'File Uploaded!',
          file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}`
        });
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(422).json(err.errors[0].message);
      });

    }
  }
})
```

})

Comment: "Ajax can't handle image uploads" - incorrect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object

Answer (score -1):

> The image file uploads successful, however the user will be redirected to "/upload".

A redirect happens when the browser asks for one URL but the server says "What you want it at this other URL, get that instead".

You aren't experiencing a redirect. The `action` just tells the browser to submit the data to `/upload`.

---

> I had attempted to setup an express route to redirect the user to the previous page, but it seems like express can't get the route since neither of the console.log() are being executed.

Your route is for `get()` but you have `method="POST"`.

To handle a request for a POST request you need a `post()` handler. The same one that actually processes the form submission!

Comment: Seems I edited the post as you were submitting this answer. I have a post route that is using Multer's upload()

Comment: @Revircs — The answer stands. You need to put the code you want to run when the POST request is made in the post handler. You've put it in a get handler.

Comment: Oh wow, I apologize. I understand what you are saying now. Thank you very much for the help!